# Installation procedure for numpy and other python-3.4 packages on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python3

I am new to ubuntu and installed ubuntu 14.04 32 bit on my LENOVO hinkpad T410 machine with windows 7 two days ago but since then trying download and install python-3.4 packages (NUMPY, SCIPY) on ubuntu and not getting results. I have Downloaded IDLE through ubuntu software centre but numpy neither run for me from ubuntu software centre nor from commands.

```
    sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

it gives me:

```
    E: Unable to locate package python-numpy_1.8.1-1ubuntu1_i386
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-numpy_1.8.1-1ubuntu1_i386'
```

I also tried:

```
    pip install python-numpy
```

but it results:

```
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-numpy
    Cleaning up...
    No distributions at all found for python-numpy
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/sibte/.pip/pip.log
```

Any guide for the very beginners to ubuntu.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` first to make sure everything on the computer is up-to-date?

Comment: the trick for me was that I wasn't using the python3-numpy command. Your advice got me on the right track. thanks.

Comment: I also found that I needed to uninstall numpy for Python2 in order for numpy for Python3 to work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

This package contains Numpy for Python 3. And as you might expect, there is also a package in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 14.04 called *python3-scipy*. If you have python3-numpy and python3-scipy installed and you want to use pylab for plotting graphs, then you'll also need to install *python3-matplotlib*.

Comment: @user3269913 Let me now how it is working out for you with python3-matplotlib if you decided to also install it. python3-matplotlib is a great program that works right out of the box, but you have to get used to its graphical interface.

Comment: I am using python3-matplotlib for simple 2d 3d plotting now and finding difficulties in installing healpy (I have posted my problem in stackoverflow) I'll use mayavi and other visualization library soon .

Comment: @user3269913 I have installed and tested healpy in Ubuntu 14.04, and I posted the steps that I followed as an answer to your question at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

I first installed `pip` for python 3.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

And then installed `numpy` with `pip3`.

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Answer (score 4):

This could run too,

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-numpy
```

Comment: what's the `-y` option?

Comment: Automatically says "yes" to the prompt that you would get from `apt` otherwise.